# Left-handed game users on an Android application

Tags: java, android, user-experience

We are building an Android application for a scientific research and while in the final stages of the application, the researches came up with the question of left-handed users. The application consists of few screens in landscape mode and there is one screen with a game and there is a **joystick in the right-hand side of the screen**. This raised our wonder about the way that left-handed people use applications which feature games.

Is there any need to flip the screen (mirror image) in order for them to use? Or does left-handed users use gaming applications with the same controls for right-handed users? And if they don't - is there any tool available for android development in order to do this fix efficiently?